# functions: Failed to load function definition from source

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I got this error after I run **firebase emulators:start**

> !  functions: Failed to load function definition from source:
> FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed
> to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: missing )
> after argument list

[image]

Yesterday it was working fine! But I don't know why the error appears. This error has stopped my program from working.

*This was my attempt to fix the problem:*

I have tried to install npm requirements for **firebase** and **firebase-function** and many have been installed except peers and I don't know what it is!
I also make firebase init again.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you check reason behind [SyntaxError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list)? Can you update your question with minimal reproducible javascript code?